# Eloquent whereIn with closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to do a whereIn with a closure. Is this possible?

Normally, you would go and create it like this

```
return User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
            ->whereLang($channel)
            ->get();
```

But, what I wanted to do, is to do it with a closure - if possible. I have a database field, which has ids of users as a string (The table design is not mine, so I can't change it currently and have to work with it);

So I tried to do it like this

```
return User::whereIn('id', function () {
    return FooBar::whereFooId('u' . $user->id)->get(['users'])->toArray();
})
    ->whereLang($lang)
    ->get();
```

However, when doing that, I'm getting the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used'

I mean, in the database table I have the string with the ids stored like `1, 2, 3, 4`, so I would just need to do an `explode(', ', $ids);`. This would solve my problem, when I do it in two steps, I was just wondering if I can do it in one, with the closure. And if so, how?

Comment: You're using `$user->id` inside the closure, but you're not passing the `$user` variable to the closure with `function () use ($user)`. How is that not throwing an error before anything else?

Comment: Eh, seems like a c&p error

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do.

```
return User::whereIn('id', FooBar::lists('uid'));
```

Assuming the user ids are stored in uid field in `FooBar` table

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer. Will I be able to attach where clauses to the `lists` method, e.g. `User::lists('users')->where('x', 'y');` ?

Comment: More like `User::where('x', 'y')->lists('users');`